# Truffle - Migrate Contract to a private network in Azure

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, truffle, microsoft-azure, truffle-contract

I try to migrate a Smart Contract to a private network running in Azure. It works fine with testrpc but when I try to migrate it to the (remote) private network I always get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:116:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:414:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

What I did so far was creating and compiling the contract and modifying `truffle.js` to

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    azure: {
      network_id: xxx,
      host: "xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com",
      port: 8545   
    },
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

When I run `migrate --network azure` in the truffle console the error occurs.

Does someone know how to do it correctly? Respectively why the error occurs?

Thanks

Comment: Run this for me `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`. This will tell me whether you have or not access to your server RPC.

Comment: And maybe is `westerNeurope`, with an N ?

Comment: It seems to work as far as the error does not occur any more. I closed the truffle console and started it again and now I come one step further. Now I get the error `Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`. Do you know how I provide the authentication / password for the account provided in the configuration file via "from"?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue I managed to get this running by `geth 'OtherOptions' --unlock 0` Which will unlock the coinbase for us.

> PS: This not a good practice.

You can also unlock the coinbase using `web3.personal.unlockAccount` from the DAPP itself.

Answer (score 1):

you need to unlock your coin base
to do so use

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase,"your_pass_phrase",time_in_miliseconds)

if you specify time 0(zero) then the account was unlocked permanently, you can lock it manually.

refer [this link](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) for more options to manage your accounts